# filtering not working in "shop by" menu

Tags: navigation

I'm having a problem with "**Shop by**" left navigation menu, when I choose one link, the address bar change but no change in products list, it works only when I disable Magento's cache in "Cache Management". I use `Magento 1.9.1.0` with RWD theme.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer; i use Lesti_Fpc "Full Page Cache" extension, There was a problem with parameters in the Cache, to solve it add required parameters in the uri field at: System => Configuration => Advanced => System => Lesti FPC; Extra info at: https://gordonlesti.com/what-are-uri-params-in-lestifpc/

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if this is now solved.